# Import from Oracle To SQL Server Error

Tags: oracle, ssis, ssis-2012

My import from Oracle (Using .Net framework data provider for Oracle) to SQL works fine in the designer but not when I run the .dtsx file.

> ORA-06401 invalid designator error

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a configuration / driver issue. You should explain in more detail where it works and where it doesn't -- and are the connections defined the same way and are there same drivers

Comment: You should use Attunity's Oracle connectors for SSIS 2012: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29283

Comment: @vercelli i tried to install it but i guess in standard edition it cannot run, am i wrong ??

Comment: @Seifsammain you are right, `Required operating environment : Enterprise or Developer edition of SQL Server 2012 Integration Services`

Comment: @vercelli any suggestions in my case ?? i wanna configure the package to run it automatically,

Comment: @Seifsammain go for BiDeveloper's answer. Donwload ODAC 32bits: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html

Comment: You need to use the correct version depending on which mode your package will run, for instance 32bit on the PC (maybe) and 64bit on the server - but it is important to have the package run against the correct version of the drivers - in fact, you'll get an error if you try otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Oracle client tools on your developer machine and the
   machine where the package will run.
2. Use Native OLEDB\Oracle Provider for OLEDB for your source.
3. Don't use a TNSNames file, instead have your connection string look
   something like this:
   (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = portno)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = dbname)))

Comment: the package is working the connection is up, but after saving the package and run the package from server agent or by double click on it it gives this error

Comment: @Seifsammain Is Oracle Client installed on the server?